# How to load any XAP file with the Windows Phone 7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-7-emulator

Does anyone know if it is possible to load a windows phone 7 XAP file into the emulator without the solution or source files? In other words, can I send somebody just a XAP file so that they can test my app, without giving them the full source code?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Run this:

D:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeploy.exe

Comment: Run the XapDeploy.exe application.  Select "Windows Phone Emulator" as the target and select what .xap application you would like to run.  You might not want to have the emulator running when you deploy because that didn't work for me at first.

Comment: Works on Windows 8 / VS2012 / WP8 as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the best and easiest way.  Go to the start button and navigate to the "Windows Phone Developer Tools" folder.  Inside you'll see a program called "Application Deployment" that you can open and use to install the xap file.  It will ask you for the location of the .xap and will give the option of deploying to the emulator or to an unlocked device.  Here is the source website: http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/12/15/Windows-Phone-7-Side-Loading.aspx

Answer (score 7):

There now seems to be a solution to this in the beta release, according to [the windows phone developer blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/12/windows-phone-developer-tools-beta-released.aspx) - the following two tools ought to be able to address this problem (although I have yet to try this):

• Developer Registration Utility – Now you can unlock you Windows Phone 7 device for development purposes.

• XAP Deployment Tool – if you want to deploy XAP files directly to an unlocked device, now you can.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be deployed on any emulator.

And here the way to do it

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/023d5f73-0528-47ee-add4-9f57f7d29815

Regards

Comment: This only applies to XNA games and doesn't work for Silverlight apps.

Comment: +1 because it will help XNA devs, but unfortunately I am developing silverlight

Answer (score 2):

In the current CTP, XAPs can only be deployed from a project. So the only way of sharing your application with someone else, is to share the source.

Comment: Not true, but may have been at the time

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy the XAP file for WP7 or WP8 in emulator without having the source file!! Please follow the steps:

1. Go to the folder- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment" and run the .exe file.
2. Now you will found a Application Deployment window. Select target device. Load the XAP file. Click 'Deploy' button.
3. Emulator will be opened automatically and finally you are ready to run the app from the Emulator.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the top rated anwser. Suggest you add the WP8 path as a comment to that answer.

Comment: I'm using WP8 Emulator and I have described in that way, which I used to follow for my deployment work. @Chris Ballard