# installing .xap file in Windows Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, testing, mobile, windows-phone-8

I'm new to windows mobile development and testing, My requirement is to test an .xap file in emulator.

Can someone help me with windows.

1. How to create .xap file
2. .xap file path/location
3. how to install in emulators.

As i know for Android we can use unsigned APK to install in emulators and for iOS we can't install .IPA on simulators.
[image: This is My XAP location folder]

Visual studio Configuration 
[image]

error message while deploying in Application Deployment
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511586/how-to-load-any-xap-file-with-the-windows-phone-7-emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to develop windows phone 8 application you would be needed to have `windows 8 Operating System (64 bit)` with `Hyper-v` and `SLAT` Support.

`Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone 8` would be needed for creating apps for windows phone 8.

Create a blank windows phone app project or go for this [How to create your first app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402526(v=vs.105).aspx)

Build you Project and if there is no error Run it into Emulator by Pressing `F5` key and keeping target as `Emulator WVGA 512MB`. Your App is Deployed into Emulator.

The .xap files are located in `[Your project folder]/Bin/Debug` for `debug mode xap` and `[Your project folder]/Bin/Release` for `Release mode xap`.

You can also Deploy `Xap` file using `Application Deployment Tool` Included in windows phone 8 SDK. Just `Browse your xap` location and Deploy it to `Emulator`

Comment: where can i get [Your project folder]/Bin/Debug

Comment: its default location is C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects but while creating project if you have mentioned other place so it would be there. at a time of project creation it also ask for location to save your project

Comment: i'm unable to see .xap file in my bin please see my question for screen shot

Comment: if you got success in build then there must be a debug/Release folder and in that you would find your xap. you got that because you would have given target os as windows phone 8.1 instead of windows phone 8.0 at startup of project creation. if using vs2013 then select template as visual c#->store apps->windows phone apps and select blank app (windows phone silver light) and ok

Comment: i have only 8.1 , what should i do

Comment: Recreate Project as mention in comment or follow above answer's step. If using vs2013 then select template as visual c#->store apps->windows phone apps and select blank app (windows phone silver light) and ok. Select target os as windows phone 8.0.

Comment: tnx... now i got Status: error-invalid pointer while deploying xap file using application deployment.

Comment: Thank you buddy, i don't know ur name... thank alot.. issue fixed

Comment: Please.... please.... please don't use `code formatting` for *emphasis*, ***okay?***

Answer (score 1):

When you build your project in VS you will automatically create the .xap file. You have 2 .xap files. one in `Debug` mode and other in `Release` mode.. When yyou upload you have to upload the release .xap to the market place.

The .xap files are located in `[Your project folder]/Bin/Debug` for debug mode xap and `[Your project folder]/Bin/Release` for release mode .xap.

YOu can directly install your xap file in to the emulators provided by the SDK using Visual Studio and test out your app. You have the option to select a Developer Unlocked Phone as the test device also.

You can manually install a xap file to either a developer unlocked Windows Phone or the Emulator using `Windows Phone Application Deployment` (For WP8.1) `Application Deployment` (WP8.0) software installed with the SDK

Follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632395.aspx) link to know how to manually install the app in your Device/Emulator